PostGIS calculate grid from bounding box Mapbox
I'm working on a web map using Mapbox where users draw a bounding box. For accurate distance and area calculations, I transform the bounding box into a projected coordinate system like EPSG:5072, generate a fishnet grid, perform calculations, and then transform the resulting grid cells back to 4326 for display on the map. The final grid appears titled on the web map compared to the bounding box drawn from the fishnet transformation. How do others handle this transformation workflow when users interact in mapbox but calculations must be run in a projected CRS? Are there better approaches to this?
General workflow: Users draw the bounding box in 4326 using Mapbox. Through PostGIS and an API, I transform the bounding box to 5072 for grid generation and running my distance calculations, etc. The resulting grid cells are transformed back to 4326 for display on the map.
Here's a simplified version of my SQL query:
WITH bbox AS (
    -- user defined bounding box 
    SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(-110.7557398026218, 43.481841312520174, -110.7543394789991, 43.482847894679736, 4326) AS geom
),
bbox_5072 AS (
    SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 5072) AS geom FROM bbox
),
grid_5072 AS (
    SELECT
        ST_MakePoint(x, y) AS geom
    FROM bbox_5072,
        generate_series(ST_XMin(bbox_5072.geom)::numeric, ST_XMax(bbox_5072.geom)::numeric, 30) AS x,  -- 30m intervals in x
        generate_series(ST_YMin(bbox_5072.geom)::numeric, ST_YMax(bbox_5072.geom)::numeric, 30) AS y   -- 30m intervals in y
),
    ----- Lots of other distance to calculations ran here based on the fishnet
transformed_grid AS (
    -- Transform grid cells from EPSG:5072 back to EPSG:4326
    SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 5072), 4326) AS geom FROM grid_5072
)
-- Final SELECT to output the transformed grid cells
SELECT * FROM transformed_grid;

Example of bounding box drawn and resulting fishnet on webmap:


1: ST_SquareGrid(), 2: related thread
